# This problem need to use a discrete distribution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a lake there are $N$ fish of which $R \leq N$ are marked. Suppose that $n \leq R$ fish are caught one by one, without substitution and let $M_i: = "\text{the i-th fish captured is marked}"$, $i = 1,2,3 ..., n$. What is $\mathbb{P} (M_i)$ equal to?

I found this exercise in the section of discrete distributions, but i can't find a distribution that fits to the problem because in the problem seem that the order matters.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, you're right.  I misread it.

Comment: It looks like you would have to compute $P(M_i|M_1,...,M_{n-1})P(M_1,...,M_{n-1})$ and then marginalise out the $M_1,...,M_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that exactly $k$ of the first $j$ fish captured have been marked is $${{R\choose k}{N-R\choose j-k}\over{N\choose j}},\ 0\leq k\leq j,$$ because there are ${R\choose k}$ ways to choose the marked fish, ${N-R\choose j-k}$ ways to choose the unmarked fish, and ${N\choose j}$ $j$ ways to choose the fish that are captured.

To calculate the probability that fish number $i$ is marked, we are interested in the case $j=i-1.$

Do you see how to continue from here?